# Angular how to display a message if data from api is 0 or empty

Tags: angular

I have a get request from an api, called in as a service into my component, I would like to display a message if the data result is 0 or empty.

**Component.ts**

```
 public errorApi = false;


 ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getIncidents(this.customer_id).subscribe((data) => {
      this.loading = true;
      this.data = data.result;
      this.loading = false;
      console.log('Result - ', data);
      console.log('data is received');
    })
    }
}
```

**Service.ts**

```
  getIn(customerId): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.serviceApiUrl + "?customer_id=" + customerId)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

**html ngif**

```
      <ng-container *ngIf="errorApi">
        <div class="column col-12 text-center pt-10 pb-10">
          <div class="">Error nothing loaded</div>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
```

Comment: How does 'data' look like when response its empty? You are able to display error by checking this 'data' variable instead of using additional one 'errorApi'.

Comment: if(!!data) { ... }  else { ... show error message }. Simple as that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `subscribe` callback, just check if `data.result == null || data.result === 0 || data.result.length === 0`, and set `errorApi` to `true` if this is the case.

```
this.service.getIncidents(this.customer_id).subscribe((data) => {
  this.loading = true; // ?? off-topic, but this seems nonsense, you should set it to true, before the subscribe
  this.data = data.result;
  this.loading = false;
  console.log('Result - ', data);
  console.log('data is received');

  errorApi = data.result == null || data.result === 0 || data.result.length === 0;
})
```

Comment: note : quickly written and untested, there might be some typo

Comment: quick question if I wanted to wrap my table in a ng-container to show only when there is data would it be something like: `showTable = this.data.result;`

Comment: Yes, you can do that. However, be careful to check that `data` is not null as well. (`this.data && this.data.result`). If you use the condition directly in the in the "*ngIf", you can make use of the safe-navigation operator like this : `*ngIf="this.data?.result"`.

Answer (score 2):

Edit your component.ts like below,

```
 public errorApi = false;


     ngOnInit() {
        this.service.getIncidents(this.customer_id).subscribe(
       (success) => {
          this.loading = true;
          this.data = success.result;
          this.loading = false;
          console.log('Result - ', data);
          console.log('data is received');
        },
       (error) => {
         this.errorApi = true;
         console.log('Error state from API:,' error)}

)
        }
    }
```

And this is your component side,

```
   <ng-container *ngIf="!data">
    <div class="column col-12 text-center pt-10 pb-10">
          <div class="">Error nothing loaded</div>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngIf="errorApi>
       <p>API error happened.</p>
      </ng-container>
```

Comment: The error handling is a good suggestion in general. However, in OP's case, there doesn't seem to be an actual HTTP error, but rather a specific value that iss not satisfying for its front end.

Comment: @Pac0 Using *ngIf="!data" approach, he can avoid to use extra variable like errorApi.

Comment: correct if "invalid data is `null`/ `undefined` / `0`, but this won't work for an empty array or empty object (as `[]` and `{}` are *truthy* values). OP was quite vague on its data, and mentioned "if data is empty..."

Comment: however, he can of course put some more complex condition in the ngIf directly, and as you suggest this will avoid a component variable : `*ngIf="!data || data.length === 0"` for instance, to check for empty array as well

Comment: Yes, `*ngIf="!data || data.length === 0"` can be used here, personally I'm not recommended to use errorApi variable, because actually it's not an error state from API. It's just a case when there is no data returning from service. If its actually API error, then in `subscription => (error)` block should be executed, not `subscription => (success)`